# Same BLoC event not triggering more than one time

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I've `HomeBloc` from `HomeView` class. Basic UI architecture is as following:

```
HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
    BlocProvider( child: HomeBody(), bloc: new HomeBloc() )
}

HomeBody extends StatefulWidget {
    createState => HomeBodyState()
}

HomeBodyState extends State {
    BlocBuilder(
        bloc: BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>()
        child: Container(
            child: Column(
                children: [
                    BlocProvider( child: CashFlowView, bloc: new HomeBloc() )
                ]
            )
        )
    )
}

CashFlowView extends StatefulWidget {
    createState => CashFlowState()
}

CashFlowState extends State {
    BlocBuilder(
        bloc: BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>()
        child: Container(
            child: Column(
                children: [
                    ChipGroupWidget(
                      onClick => BlocProvider.of().add(event) //  <----- Problem is here
                    )
                ]
            )
        )
    )
}
```

Whole code can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/shafayathossain/Expense-Manager-Flutter-).
Problem is when any `Chip` inside my `ChipGroup` is tapped, a callback function is called in `CashFlowState`. Inside that, a bloc event is added to bloc with some data. But it is triggering only for first time. What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4):

From the [bloc library documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/faqs?id=state-not-updating)
Extend your state class with equatable and after each event emit a new state (same type) with the new properyties (data)

Answer (score 2):

In flutter bloc pattern system, the UI is rebuilt only when the state changes. If in any case when a fired event triggers the same state currently the bloc is in, the build function won't be called again, i.e, the UI won't be rebuilt.

In your case, when for the first time the `CashFlowState` is yielded, the whole code works just fine. But then the same state is yielded again, the event is triggered, but the build function isn't being called again, because the state never changed.

What you have to do is, create two different states along with two different events. Lets say, `chipTappedEvent` will yield `chipTappedState`, and `chipResetEvent` will yield `chipResetState`.

In the beginning you can use `chipResetState` or any other state as initial state. Then when the user taps on a chip, just trigger the `chipTappedEvent` which should yield `chipTappedState`.

In your listener, listen for the state `chipTappedState` and do what you have to do. Then immediately trigger the `chipResetEvent` which should yield `chipResetState`. In this way, when the user taps the chip again, the yielded state will be `chipTappedState` which will be different from `chipResetState`, so the build function will be called again.